# Android media player doesn't play

Tags: c#, android, media-player

The media player runs on the emulator or real device without any errors, but when I click on the start button the media doesn't start or give any sound. I've tried to remove `else` from `PreparePlayer` method and it works, but takes a very long time to open.

```
    SeekBar seekBar1;
    System.Timers.Timer t;

    t = new System.Timers.Timer();
    t.Interval = 3000;
    t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(t_Elapsed);

    string filePath = "http://server10.mp3quran.net/ajm/128/001.mp3";
    PreparePlayer(filePath);
    Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bustart);
    button.Click += delegate
    {

        if (!player.IsPlaying)
        {
            button.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.pauseicon);
            player.Start();
            t.Start();

        }
        else
        {
            button.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.starticonn);
            player.Pause();
            t.Stop();

        }

    };
protected MediaPlayer player;
public void PreparePlayer(String filePath)
{
    if (player == null)
    {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
    }
    else
    {
        player.Reset();
        player.SetDataSource(filePath);
        player.Prepare();

        seekBar1.Max = player.Duration;
    }
}
protected void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    seekBar1.Progress = player.CurrentPosition;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Streaming functions.

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

This is not a FilePath.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html